# How can I build a function concept with a particular signature?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I'm writing some generic software using concepts and I want to check if a particular function symbol name exists with a signature of (void)(int,int) on a struct. To do this I've I'm thinking of approaching this problem through template specialization but I'm sort of lost.

What I want is something to work and through compile time errors if the concept is not satisfied like so:

```
struct TypeA {
  // Passes concept
  void process (int a ,int b) const {};
};

struct TypeB {
  // Does not pass concept
  void process (float a) const {};
};

struct TestConcepts {
  /* concept code here */
  TestConcepts(T t) {
    process_concept(t.process);
  };
};

int main(void) {
  // Should pass
  TestConcept(TypeA{});
  // Should throw error
  TestConcept(TypeB{});
  return 0;
}
```

I'm having a hard time filling in the blanks but this is what I have so far:

```
struct TestConcepts {
      /* concept code here */
      struct process_concept {
        process_concept((V*)(IA,IB)){
            if (is_integral<IA>::value && is_integral<IB>::value && is_same<V, void>) {
                return;
            }
            static_assert(false, "You must provide function called process of type (void)(int,int)");
        };
    };
      TestConcepts(T t) {
        process_concept(&t.process);
      };
    };
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. How can I get this function signature correct?

Comment: I'd say you mix your terminology, since what you seem to want is a *trait* and not a concept (which in C++ means something completely different and is supposed to be a syntactic part of future language specifications).

Comment: Ya, I'm very new to this generic programming stuff. From the documentation it sounds like traits and concepts were related or very similar to me. But I understand that a concept limits the types of template parameters that can be used by some "base interface". It also promises certain types of traits that the non-inherited type will have. When I say type, I extend that to mean structs/ classes/ functions etc.. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: Please, explain why my question is too broad. I have code which is specific to the problem I'm solving. I have question asking what is wrong with my code signature. I explain there may be concepts that I don't understand but I show what I am trying to accomplish. I spent quality time making this as clear as possible.

Is stack overflow only for experts?

Comment: The [c++-concepts] tag suggests you want to know how to do this using the proposed concepts language features which are likely coming in 2020, but are not yet in an official C++ Standard. If you want a solution that works with C++17, you should probably remove that tag.

Comment: I somewhat disagree. Concepts are available through design patterns or boost libs. Learning how to do them right in regardless of c++17 or c++20 is what I want.

Comment: @Dr.Knowitall updated my answer. just for your insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a function that returns a declared function pointer?

```
struct TypeA {
    // Passes concept
    void process (int a ,int b) const {};
};

struct TypeB {
    // Does not pass concept
    void process (float a) const {};
};

template<typename T>
auto TestConcepts(T) -> void(T::*)(int, int) const
{
    return &T::process;
}

int main(void) {
    // Should pass
    TestConcepts(TypeA{});
    // Should throw error
    TestConcepts(TypeB{});
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Error(s):

source_file.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void (T::* TestConcepts(T))(int, int) const [with T = TypeB]’:
source_file.cpp:26:23:   required from here
source_file.cpp:19:16: error: cannot convert ‘void (TypeB::*)(float) const’ to ‘void (TypeB::*)(int, int) const’ in return
     return &T::process;
                ^
```

## EDIT: more options

If you want to include `void process(long int a, long int b) const;` or `void process(int a, int b, int c=0) const;`, like aschepler is suggesting, you can use type traits.

```
struct TypeA {
    // Passes concept
    void process(int a, int b) const {};
};

struct TypeB {
    // Does not pass concept
    void process(float a) const {};
};

struct TypeC {
    // Passes concept
    void process(long int a, long int b) const {};
};

struct TypeD {
    // Passes concept
    void process(int a, int b, int c = 0) const {};
};

struct TypeE {
    // Does not pass concept
    void process(int a, int b, int c) const {};
};

#include <type_traits>
template<typename T, typename A1, typename A2, typename... An>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_integral<A1>::value &&
    std::is_integral<A2>::value
>::type
TestProcess(const T& t, void(T::*)(A1, A2, An...) const) {
    t.process(1, 2);
};

template<typename T>
void TestConcepts(const T& t)
{
    TestProcess(t, &T::process);
}

int main(void) {
    // Passes
    TestConcepts(TypeA{});
    // Throws compilation error
    TestConcepts(TypeB{});
    // Passes
    TestConcepts(TypeC{});
    // Passes
    TestConcepts(TypeD{});
    // Throws compilation error
    TestConcepts(TypeE{});

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice design pattern! Thanks, this really helped!

Comment: Note this will fail if the type has for example `void process(long int a, long int b) const;` or `void process(int a, int b, int c=0) const;`. Whether this is correct depends on exactly what you want.

Comment: @aschepler good point. I'm still learning myself. Maybe you could propose a better answer?

Comment: @aschepler I've been thinking about it, and edited the solution to include an extended version with type traits.